# IE: Unicode characters in HTML select and option tags

Tags: html, internet-explorer, unicode, html-select

I need show options in a select with unicode characters. Try this:

```
<select id="ddlNota_CateId">
<option value="1091">&#26641;&#31435;&#20351;&#29992;ICT&#30340;</option>
</select>
```

And show unrecognized charcaters (树立使用ICT的). :s

Example in http://200.115.217.50/test.html

Comment: I don't understand at all what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: I threw that snippet into a bare .html file and it showed just fine on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I need show chinese charcaters in the select options

Comment: The problem is in IE. Chrome and FF show ok :s.

Comment: What version of IE? Can you post a sample file (minimal - just the <head> and your <select> tag in the <body>)? What is shown (screenshot)?

Comment: Works fine here in IE6/7/8. This is definitely a client-specific font problem.

Comment: Specified link isn't working anymore :( - You should have posted the example code here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IE you'll need to explicitly set fonts in your CSS that have those characters. Unfortunately it's impossible to know which fonts your visitors have, so you'll need to add a list of popular ones. For example:

```
body {
   font-family: Arial Unicode MS, Lucida Sans Unicode, Code2000, sans-serif; //etc.
}
```

Comment: You'll of course need one of those fonts installed. If you know a font on your system that supports those characters add that font to the start of the list.

Comment: Arial Unicode MS is installed in WinXp by default. I see in Control Panel / Fonts. But not show ok.

Answer (score 3):

A [numeric character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#entities) in HTML *always* uses characters from Unicode. For example, the first character #26641 refers to [U+2611](http://freecog.net/2006/unicodedb/U+6811/), which is a Chinese character 树.

The characters that you pasted into the question appear correctly as well. This is almost certainly a browser, font, or operating system problem. For example, if you see squares instead of characters, the browser does not have a proper font. Some browsers will automatically choose a font that has the characters you need, but you might need to explicitly set the font-family in others.

Try [Help:Multilingual support (East Asian)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Multilingual_support_%28East_Asian%29) on Wikipedia.

Comment: I agree, probably a font problem. IE is less good at falling back to a font containing a character not present in the page's chosen font.

Comment: But, in http://200.115.217.50/test.html show ok in HTML and not show ok in select / option

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` header, and/or `<meta charset="utf-8">` if you are directly entering the japanese/chinese/unicode characters in ( not html entities ).

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/nP87F/1/

**HTML entities should work regardless**, though. **Are you sure it isn't just your text editor or OS** that doesn't support that language set?

If you're on Windows these might be helpful:

- http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_install_languages.mspx?mfr=true
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chinese_(Mandarin)/Displaying_Chinese_Characters

Comment: Can you be way more specific?

Comment: But, in 200.115.217.50/test.html show ok in HTML and not show ok in select / option

Comment: What OS? Windows? You are most def. missing a language pack.

Comment: WinXP SP3 English. But, I try with Chrome or FF and show Ok. Is not a font problem of OS.

Comment: What font-family do you have it set to? Did you try specifying a different font?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the font setting in the style declaration. You're telling the browser to use a specific font that clearly doesn't support the characters you need.

Comment: I removed. But the problem is the same. With Chrome and FF the unicode characters show ok.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see:

- The font name should be "Arial Unicode MS", exactly like that, or the exact name of another suitable font.
- Your web server (IIS) isn't serving this as UTF-8. I get the following:

  $ curl --head http://200.115.217.50/test.html
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Length: 874
  Content-Type: text/html
  Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Aug 2010 15:56:14 GMT
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  ETag: "6ae315ba6d39cb1:1d22"
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Wed, 11 Aug 2010 16:11:48 GMT

  It should be `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

**ALSO, please next time post your code and URL clearly in the main question for everyone to see -- you are sending people on wild guessing games otherwise.**

Comment: The URL is in main question (Example in: ...) and chrome and FF show ok the select / option.